# Projects to do to build PySpark portfolio

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am newbie to PySpark. And I would like to know what are some projects that I can develop using PySpark. So that I can build my PySpark portfolio and show to prospective employer that I can work on PySpark projects. Appreciate your help as always.

Answer (score 1):

PySpark can be used for various different scenarios, but assuming that *Data Analytics* is probably its most common application (which includes lots of transformations), I would suggest getting familiar with Spark SQL syntax, by trying out exercises on [Kaggle Datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets).

Given the wide variety of different data formats and different use cases you will find there, it should give a good understanding of what to expect when working on Spark project full-time and also earn some credibility, which might be valuable for your portfolio :)

Comment: Thanks! that is worth checking. Also I would like to know what data engineering projects I can built using Spark(Python/Java)? The stuff like ETL/data pipeline etc.

Comment: I know that some course sites had some courses (paid unfortunately) that would teach you with examples on how to do the ETL pipelines with Spark and so on. Maybe this one (just random pick) will sound interesting to you - https://www.packtpub.com/product/hands-on-big-data-analytics-with-pyspark/9781838644130 ?